# I want the "Edit" button to open a new window and then be able to edit the values on the display

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button

I want the "Edit" button to open a new window and then be able to edit the values on the display. For example I want it to open a window with "Daniel Keelagher" and then be able to either +1 or -1 from Games Played, Goals, Assists etc. Please be detailed with your answer as i am dumb and a beginner coder.

````
#Edit Function

root = Tk()
#Labels
lblTitle = Label(text="Chelsea FC Player Statistics",font=('bold', 15), fg="blue",).grid(row=0, column=1)
#Player Names Labels
lblPlayerNames = Label(text="Player Names",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=1)
lblDKName = Label(text="Daniel Keelagher").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=1)
lblJKName = Label(text="Joseph Keelagher").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=1)
lblBMName = Label(text="Benjamin Miller").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=1)
lblJTName = Label(text="Jordan Terlato").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=1)
#Matches Played Labels
lblMatchesPlayed = Label(text="Matches Played",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=2)
lblDKMatches = Label(text="10").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=2)
lblJKMatches = Label(text="9").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=2)
lblBMMatches = Label(text="9").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=2)
lblJTMatches = Label(text="8").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=2)
#Goals Labels
lblGoals = Label(text="Goals",font=('bold')).grid(row=1, column=3)
lblDKGoals = Label(text="4").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=3)
lblJKGoals = Label(text="2").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=3)
lblBMGoals = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=3)
lblJTGoals = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=3)
#Assists Labels
lblAssists = Label(text="Assists",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=4)
lblDKAssists = Label(text="4").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=4)
lblJKAssists = Label(text="2").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=4)
lblBMAssists = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=4)
lblJTAssists = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=4)
#YellowCards Labels
lblYellowCards = Label(text="YC",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=5)
lblDKYellowCards = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=5)
lblJKYellowCards = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=5)
lblBMYellowCards = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=5)
lblJTYellowCards = Label(text="3").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=5)
#RedCards Labels
lblYellowCards = Label(text="RC",font=('bold')).grid(columnspan=1,row=1, column=6)
lblDKRedCards = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=6)
lblJKRedCards = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=6)
lblBMRedCards = Label(text="0").grid(columnspan=1,row=4, column=6)
lblJTRedCards = Label(text="1").grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=6)


#Buttons
btnDKEdit = Button(root, text="Edit",).grid(columnspan=1,row=2, column=7)
btnJKEdit = Button(root, text="Edit", ).grid(columnspan=1,row=3, column=7)
btnBMEdit = Button(root, text="Edit", ).grid(columnspan=1,row=4,column=7)
btbJTEdit = Button(root, text="Edit",).grid(columnspan=1,row=5, column=7)```
````

Comment: SO is not a place for asking sample code.  Suggest to go through some tutorials on `tkinter`, especially on creating window using `Toplevel` and using `Entry` widgets.  Then raise question on the problem come across when you try to achieve your goal.

Comment: @acw1668 yeh but i have no idea how to do it :( i assume its a function but idk

Comment: It's much more than a simple function. First, you need to define `StringVar()` objects to link your labels to. These objects may be changed to change the values on screen. Then, you will need to store them in a way that is accessible from a function (e.g. put them in a global list or incorporate the whole widget in a class with shared attributes). Then, you need the function to open a new window with a store button that links to the real function. This function has to read all the values from Entry widgets and set the StringVar() for each field new. You need tutorials, not code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (pretty long but I will try to explain most of the parts as best as I can (explanation below) however in this case there won't be a new window and also this is more of an example of how that might be done just to give You an idea.):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, Label, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Separator
from functools import partial


stored_data = {'Lionel Notmessi': {'Games Played': 340, 'Goals': 102, 'Assists': 223}, 'Firstname Lastname': {'Games Played': 279, 'Goals': 84, 'Assists': 56}}


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.players_frame = Frame(self)
        self.players_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.data_value_list = []

        for index, player in enumerate(list(stored_data)):
            player_frame = Frame(self.players_frame)
            player_frame.pack(side='left')
            Label(player_frame, text=player, height=2, width=30, anchor='n', font='default 11 bold').pack(side='top', pady=10)

            var = StringVar()
            self.data_value_list.append(var)

            Label(player_frame, textvariable=self.data_value_list[index], height=8, width=30).pack(side='top', pady=10)

            Button(player_frame, text='Edit', command=partial(self.select, player)).pack(side='bottom', pady=10, fill='x', expand=True)

        self.refresh_data()

    def select(self, key):
        self.players_frame.pack_forget()
        player_edit_frame = EditData(self, stored_data, key)
        player_edit_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    def refresh_data(self):
        for var, player in zip(self.data_value_list, list(stored_data)):
            data = ''
            for name, value in stored_data[player].items():
                data += f'{name}: {value}\n\n'
            var.set(data)


class EditData(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, data, key):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data
        self.key = key

        self.total_width = len(list(data[key].keys()))

        name = Label(self, text=key, anchor='n', height=3)
        name.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew', pady=10)

        self.value_list = []
        index = 0
        for key, value in data[self.key].items():
            item_frame = Frame(self)
            item_frame.grid(row=1, column=index, sticky='nsew', padx=5)
            for i in range(3):
                item_frame.columnconfigure(i, minsize=50)

            var = StringVar()
            var.set(value)
            self.value_list.append(var)

            Label(item_frame, text=key).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

            minus = Button(item_frame, text='-', command=partial(self.change, self.value_list[index], '-', key))
            minus.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

            value_label = Label(item_frame, textvariable=self.value_list[index])
            value_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

            plus = Button(item_frame, text='+', command=partial(self.change, self.value_list[index], '+', key))
            plus.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nsew')

            index += 1

        Separator(self, orient='horizontal').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew', pady=5)

        Button(self, text='Done', command=self.done).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew')

    def change(self, var, operator, key):
        current = var.get()
        if operator == '-':
            total = int(current) - 1
            var.set(str(total))
            self.data[self.key][key] = total
        if operator == '+':
            total = int(current) + 1
            var.set(str(total))
            self.data[self.key][key] = total

    def done(self):
        self.parent.refresh_data()
        self.parent.players_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
        self.destroy()


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

So the first thing is to import all the necessary modules that will be used.

Next I set a variable `stored_data` to a dictionary which will be the main data storage place where all the data about players will be stored.

Then I created a class called `MainWindow` which inherits from `Tk` which is the main window of tkinter so that way it is possible to get the `Tk()` functionality for example the `.mainloop()` method.

In the `MainWindow` constructor method (what will get called on initiating) first I set the window to unresizable in both x and y directions so to not cause problems with widgets not being visible.

Then I created a frame to organize where all the player stuff will be displayed and also created another list for storing StringVar values so that it is easy to update the current data labels (the ones that are seen when launching the program).

Then for each key in the dictionary I created a frame to again organize displayed widgets. Then in the frame I packed all the stuff that is related, I put in the player name, their stats and the edit button (since I was focusing only on that functionality). Also appended a StringVar to list for each of the players. Those StringVar set the value of the label that will display the stats. And the StringVar is accessed by index.

Then I called `self.refresh_data()` which basically sets a value for each StringVar in the list to the according dictionary values. Basically displays stats.

Then there is also the `select()` method defined (it is called by a button) which initiates `EditData` and then puts it on the screen after removing the `self.players_frame` from the geometry manager so that it is no more visible and only the edit frame is visible.

The `EditData` class. Upon being initiated it takes the argument given to it and sets them as class attributes for easier access across the class.

Then total width is measured to calculate the columnspan of the grid and it is done by mesuring the length of list created by `stored_data` keys so basically the length is the amount of players.

Then the name is put on screen.

Again is created another `self.value_list` for storing StringVar and an index is set to 0 (since I couldn't figure out how to implement it (easy enough) in the for loop (using `enumerate()`)). and the index is increased every iteration.

Then Labels and button are created and gridded to the `item_frame` which is inside the class which inherits from Frame so basically the class is a bigger Frame and inside it the program creates smaller frames for data changing and layout organization purposes. Then inside the `item_frame` each column is set to minsize=50 so that they are the same size since none of the data takes up that much space anyways.

Then again a StringVar is set and appended to the list to access it later.

The whole

```
  name 
- data +
```

layout is created and buttons are set to the method `change()` and given the arguments (the `partial()` sets those function to always execute with the same given variables so that it is possible to create buttons in a loop easily). When change is called it get the current value of that data part and then depending on whether it is a "-" or "+" it adds or subtracts from the current value and sets it as the new value and also changes the value in the dictionary so that next time this frames is show it shows the new data and so that the stats on the "front page" show the updated data.

There is also the "Done" button which when pressed calls the `done()` method which then calls parent (which is `MainWindow`) method `refresh_data()` to display the new data, then it packs back that frame that was removed before when calling this class and then destroys itself.

And then we just initiate `MainWindow`:

```
root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

And that is it.

Obviously some design improvements can be done.
Also if You wanted to save data so that the changed data shows every time You start You can write the data to a file before closing the window.

If You have questions just ask them.

About that file saving:

You can add this (`MainWindow` class):

```
self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda: self.save(stored_data))
```

to the `__init__` method to execute the function given when closing the window

also add this:

```
with open('stored_data.json') as file:
    stored_data = json.load(file)
```

at the start of You file but make sure that You have that file in Your directory also You have to:

```
import json
```

and then define the `save()` method (in the `MainWindow` class) that is called when closing the window:

```
def save(self, data):
        with open('stored_data.json', 'w') as file_:
            json.dump(data, file_, indent=2)
        self.destroy()
```

so that it writes the updated data to that file and remember to destroy the window afterwards otherwise it won't close.

Now You are able to load data when running the program and if You make changes they will be saved to the file to access them next time You run the program.

Again if You have questions ask them.

Added Toplevel (really minimal changes but added a few things like bind to make sure that if user focuses out of the edit window it gets closed so that multiple same windows are not open (so also defined another method), all changes below):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame, Label, StringVar, Toplevel, Entry
from tkinter.ttk import Separator
from functools import partial


stored_data = {'Lionel Notmessi': {'Games Played': 340, 'Goals': 102, 'Assists': 223}, 'Firstname Lastname': {'Games Played': 279, 'Goals': 84, 'Assists': 56}}


class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.players_frame = Frame(self)
        self.players_frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

        self.data_value_list = []

        for index, player in enumerate(list(stored_data)):
            player_frame = Frame(self.players_frame)
            player_frame.pack(side='left')
            Label(player_frame, text=player, height=2, width=30, anchor='n', font='default 11 bold').pack(side='top', pady=10)

            var = StringVar()
            self.data_value_list.append(var)

            Label(player_frame, textvariable=self.data_value_list[index], height=8, width=30).pack(side='top', pady=10)

            Button(player_frame, text='Edit', command=partial(self.select, player)).pack(side='bottom', pady=10, fill='x', expand=True)

        self.refresh_data()

    def select(self, key):
        player_edit_frame = EditData(self, stored_data, key)
        player_edit_frame.focus_force()

    def refresh_data(self):
        for var, player in zip(self.data_value_list, list(stored_data)):
            data = ''
            for name, value in stored_data[player].items():
                data += f'{name}: {value}\n\n'
            var.set(data)


class EditData(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, data, key):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data
        self.key = key

        self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.focus_out)

        self.total_width = len(list(data[key].keys()))

        name = Label(self, text=key, anchor='n', height=3)
        name.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew', pady=10)

        self.value_list = []
        index = 0
        for key, value in data[self.key].items():
            item_frame = Frame(self)
            item_frame.grid(row=1, column=index, sticky='nsew', padx=5)
            for i in range(3):
                item_frame.columnconfigure(i, minsize=50)

            var = StringVar()
            var.set(value)
            self.value_list.append(var)

            Label(item_frame, text=key).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')

            minus = Button(item_frame, text='-', command=partial(self.change, self.value_list[index], '-', key))
            minus.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

            value_label = Label(item_frame, textvariable=self.value_list[index])
            value_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='nsew')

            plus = Button(item_frame, text='+', command=partial(self.change, self.value_list[index], '+', key))
            plus.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nsew')

            index += 1

        Separator(self, orient='horizontal').grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew', pady=5)

        Button(self, text='Done', command=self.done).grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=self.total_width, sticky='nsew')

    def change(self, var, operator, key):
        current = var.get()
        if operator == '-':
            total = int(current) - 1
            var.set(str(total))
            self.data[self.key][key] = total
        if operator == '+':
            total = int(current) + 1
            var.set(str(total))
            self.data[self.key][key] = total

    def done(self):
        self.parent.refresh_data()
        self.destroy()

    def focus_out(self, event):
        self.parent.refresh_data()
        if event.widget == self:
            self.destroy()


root = MainWindow()
root.mainloop()
```

Change in `MainWindow`:

Changed the `select()` method to show the Toplevel

```py
def select(self, key):
        player_edit_frame = EditData(self, stored_data, key)
        player_edit_frame.focus_force()
```

Changes in `EditFrame`:

Inherited from Toplevel

```py
class EditData(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, data, key):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
```

Added bind

```py
self.bind('<FocusOut>', self.focus_out)
```

A method to come with bind (it checks if the focus is out of the whole window, otherwise even focusing out of an entry widget would cause it to close)

```py
def focus_out(self, event):
        self.parent.refresh_data()
        if event.widget == self:
            self.destroy()
```

Comment: Updated my answer with the option to save files

Comment: thank you so much for this detailed answer, how would I implement this with my code, so that when I press the "Edit" it opens a new window with the exact player name and stats. Seriously I cant thank you enough for your help. This would be the cherry on top if you could implement this with my code.

Comment: @Volted I added the code (at the bottom) to include Toplevel. Now it is almost impossible to implement my approach into Your code because my approach uses a completely different way of storing data, creating labels and so on, because Your approach is very hardcoded, while I use a dictionary to strore data and create widgets based on need (using a for loop) so it would be verry hard to implement. Also my answer is pretty much a complete thing and was meant as an example however the reason I explained so much was for You to maybe learn something from this and try implementing it Yourself.

Comment: Also if You want to do this Yourself it is not necessary to use classess, I think it may as well be done with functions (maybe not as easy from my point of view (also not as compact)) but if You don't know anything about classes (which I suggest You use for GUI's) I suggest [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM&list=PL-osiE80TeTsqhIuOqKhwlXsIBIdSeYtc) (more like series but it should help). Obviously ask if You have questions about something.

Comment: so if its almost impossible to implement this into my code, can i somehow recode it so that I still have the same look/concept?? Are you able to add the beginning part linking to the "edit" button from the code that you made? Tysm

Comment: @Volted the reason it is almost impossible is because You (at least from the code posted) don't even use functions, You are hardcoding everything (not the biggest problem) and though it probably is possible to do this without classes (You would still need functions) it will be a bit longer and may not be so flexible. It also depends on what You mean by implement because the one implementation I see is copy paste and overwrite Your code which wouldn't be great for Your own development since it would be hard for You to understand what stuff does.

Comment: @Volted I can and probably will try making it a bit simpler (more Your style) by that I won't use classes but I will certainly use dictionaries and functions but it should be simpler so at some point I will post another answer with that code

Comment: Thanks so much, this is for a school project so thats why I am kinda a basic coder and want it done for my soccer team in real life using player names and actual statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this (functional programming way):

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Button, Label, StringVar, Toplevel
from functools import partial


stored_data = {'Lionel Notmessi': {'Games Played': 340, 'Goals': 102, 'Assists': 223}, 'Firstname Lastname': {'Games Played': 279, 'Goals': 84, 'Assists': 56}}


def open_edit_window(player):
    tp = Toplevel(root)
    tp.focus_force()

    def del_n_refresh(event=None):
        tp.destroy()
        pack_all_players()

    tp.bind('<FocusOut>', del_n_refresh)
    tp.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', del_n_refresh)

    total_length = len(stored_data[player])

    def change(variable, stat_name, sign):
        current = int(variable.get())
        if sign == '-':
            stored_data[player][stat_name] = current - 1
            variable.set(current - 1)
        elif sign == '+':
            stored_data[player][stat_name] = current + 1
            variable.set(current + 1)

    stats_edit_frame = Frame(tp)
    stats_edit_frame.pack()

    Label(stats_edit_frame, text=player).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=total_length)

    value_list = []
    
    counter = 0
    for stats, values in stored_data[player].items():
        var = StringVar()
        var.set(values)
        value_list.append(var)

        edit_data_frame = Frame(stats_edit_frame)
        edit_data_frame.grid(row=1, column=counter, padx=5, pady=5)
        for i in range(3):
            edit_data_frame.columnconfigure(i, minsize=50)

        Label(edit_data_frame, text=stats).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

        Button(edit_data_frame, text='-', command=partial(change, value_list[counter], stats, '-')).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        Label(edit_data_frame, textvariable=value_list[counter]).grid(row=1, column=1)

        Button(edit_data_frame, text='+', command=partial(change, value_list[counter], stats, '+')).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='nsew')
        counter += 1

    done = Button(stats_edit_frame, text='Done', command=del_n_refresh)
    done.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=total_length, sticky='nsew', pady=5, padx=5)


def pack_all_players():
    # this for loop is for refreshing the data
    for widget in all_player_frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

    for player in stored_data:
        player_frame = Frame(all_player_frame, width=100)
        player_frame.pack(side='left', pady=20, padx=20)

        Label(player_frame, text=player, font='default 12 normal').pack(side='top', pady=5)

        stats_frame = Frame(player_frame)
        stats_frame.pack(side='top', pady=10)
        for stats, values in stored_data[player].items():
            Label(stats_frame, text=f'{stats}: {values}').pack()

        Button(player_frame, text='Edit', width=15, command=partial(open_edit_window, player)).pack(side='bottom', pady=5)


root = Tk()

all_player_frame = Frame(root)
all_player_frame.pack()

pack_all_players()

root.mainloop()
```

So the process is already explained in the other answer and here it is pretty much the same, almost the same loops, almost the same calls, but using functions instead of classes. If You ask whether this would be possible to implement: then if You mean just adding these functions to Your code (the one You have posted) then these functions just do everything, literally, therefore the only implementation would be to copy paste over Your code, then You could also change some of the functions, modify them and so on because they create widgets based on need, so basically the amount of players there are in the dictionary the amount of according widgets this will create (Your approach seems to hardcode information). and again if You want to save to a file that I also covered in the other answer.

Comment: Seriously thank you so much for your hard effort. When combining the codes I am not sure how to link them together with the 4 names and that data. Would you be able to link the Edit button over to my original code with those 4 names and statistics.  ? I know im asking for a lot but i would be forever greatful <3 Sorry for being so bad at coding

Comment: Seriously thank you so much for your hard effort. When combining the codes I am not sure how to link them together with the 4 names and that data. Would you be able to link the Edit button over to my original code with those 4 names and statistics. ? I know im asking for a lot but i would be forever greatful <3 Sorry for being so bad at coding

Comment: @Volted I could make Your edit buttons open a new window but the issue is that You don't store the data, You cannot just put it in labels You have to create a dictionary (because that is the easiest way) and put data on labels from the dictionary not the other way around. So first thing is that You create a dictionary where You will store all data (will show You exactly what I mean (Your way (almost) but I am telling You You have to learn how to use loops to create widgets because otherwise You will have to create new widgets manually every time You add more players))

Comment: thats really good, I can do the rest of the players now hopefully. The only thing I need now is the #comments for the code as I dont understand some of it saying what the code does

Comment: @Volted which code are You talking about? the most recent answer or this one (with functions)?

Comment: The one that you combined my code and used my player names with.

Comment: Comments with the "Daniel Keelagher" code.

Comment: @Volted what? I added the comments already is something still unclear? also could You comment under the according answer?

Answer (score 0):

So here it is completely Your way (at least the closest I could find and also the worst way to go about this but You do You):

```py
# import what is necessary
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, IntVar, Toplevel
import json

# first try doing this code of block and if it raises the FileNotFoundError use the other bloc
try:
    # open 'settings.json' file and load the data (import json first)
    with open('settings.json') as file:
        stored_data = json.load(file)

except FileNotFoundError:
    # create sample data to add to the created file
    stored_data = {'Daniel Keelagher': {'Matches Played': 10, 'Goals': 4, 'Assists': 4, 'YC': 0, 'RC': 0},
                   'Joseph Keelagher': {'Matches Played': 9, 'Goals': 2, 'Assists': 2, 'YC': 1, 'RC': 0},
                   'Benjamin Miller': {'Matches Played': 9, 'Goals': 0, 'Assists': 0, 'YC': 1, 'RC': 0},
                   'Jordan Terlato': {'Matches Played': 8, 'Goals': 1, 'Assists': 1, 'YC': 3, 'RC': 1}}
    # create 'settings.json' file if the file was not found
    with open('settings.json', 'w') as file:
        # dump all the data in 'settings.json'
        json.dump(stored_data, file, indent=2)

# define function change which will be responsible for changing data in stored_data dictionary
def change(player, stat, value, operator):  # set required arguments for the function which will be the: player (key in the dictionary, i.e. 'Daniel Keelagher'); stat (key in the player dictionary i.e. 'Goals', 'Assists'); value (refers to the IntVar associated with the respective Label); operator (determines whether value will be subtracted or added)
    # getting the current value of the associated IntVar
    cur_value = value.get()
    # eval to determine the operation if/elif
    if operator == '-':
        # accessing the stored_data key and dictionary key under the stored_data[key]
        stored_data[player][stat] = cur_value - 1
        # setting the IntVar value
        value.set(cur_value - 1)
    elif operator == '+':
        # same as previous but adding value
        stored_data[player][stat] = cur_value + 1
        value.set(cur_value + 1)


# defining edit_dk which will be responsible for editing Daniel Keelagher so such similar functions should be created for all players i.e. edit_jk, edit_bm
def edit_dk():
    # creating a new window for data editing
    tp = Toplevel(root)

    # packing a label to display name
    Label(tp, text='Daniel Keelagher').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=15)

    # packing edit buttons and value label for data editing, command is set to change() and can be followed through using previous comments this explanation is for all the Label-Button groups below defined in this function
    Button(tp, text='-', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'Matches Played', dk_matches_var, '-')).grid(row=1, column=0)
    Label(tp, textvariable=dk_matches_var).grid(row=1, column=1)
    Button(tp, text='+', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'Matches Played', dk_matches_var, '+')).grid(row=1, column=2)

    Button(tp, text='-', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'Goals', dk_goals_var, '-')).grid(row=1, column=3)
    Label(tp, textvariable=dk_goals_var).grid(row=1, column=4)
    Button(tp, text='+', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'Goals', dk_goals_var, '+')).grid(row=1, column=5)

    Button(tp, text='-', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'Assists', dk_assists_var, '-')).grid(row=1, column=6)
    Label(tp, textvariable=dk_assists_var).grid(row=1, column=7)
    Button(tp, text='+', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'Assists', dk_assists_var, '+')).grid(row=1, column=8)

    Button(tp, text='-', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'YC', dk_yc_var, '-')).grid(row=1, column=9)
    Label(tp, textvariable=dk_yc_var).grid(row=1, column=10)
    Button(tp, text='+', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'YC', dk_yc_var, '+')).grid(row=1, column=11)

    Button(tp, text='-', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'RC', dk_rc_var, '-')).grid(row=1, column=12)
    Label(tp, textvariable=dk_rc_var).grid(row=1, column=13)
    Button(tp, text='+', command=lambda: change('Daniel Keelagher', 'RC', dk_rc_var, '+')).grid(row=1, column=14)


# initiating Tk class which also creates a window
root = Tk()

# Labels
Label(text="Chelsea FC Player Statistics", font=('bold', 15), fg="blue",).grid(row=0, column=1)

# Player Names Labels
Label(text="Player Names", font='bold').grid(columnspan=1, row=1, column=1)
Label(text="Daniel Keelagher").grid(columnspan=1, row=2, column=1)

# Matches Played Labels
Label(text="Matches Played", font='bold').grid(columnspan=1, row=1, column=2)
# setting up an IntVar for matches: for other players it could be for example bm_matches_var and is related to matches label (below) this explanation fits other IntVars too.
dk_matches_var = IntVar()
# set the variable to statistics the same for the rest
dk_matches_var.set(stored_data['Daniel Keelagher']['Matches Played'])
Label(textvariable=dk_matches_var).grid(columnspan=1, row=2, column=2)


# Goals Labels
Label(text="Goals", font='bold').grid(row=1, column=3)
dk_goals_var = IntVar()
dk_goals_var.set(stored_data['Daniel Keelagher']['Goals'])
Label(textvariable=dk_goals_var).grid(columnspan=1, row=2, column=3)

# Assists Labels
Label(text="Assists", font='bold').grid(columnspan=1, row=1, column=4)
dk_assists_var = IntVar()
dk_assists_var.set(stored_data['Daniel Keelagher']['Assists'])
Label(textvariable=dk_assists_var).grid(columnspan=1, row=2, column=4)

# YellowCards Labels
Label(text="YC", font='bold').grid(columnspan=1, row=1, column=5)
dk_yc_var = IntVar()
dk_yc_var.set(stored_data['Daniel Keelagher']['YC'])
Label(textvariable=dk_yc_var).grid(columnspan=1, row=2, column=5)

# RedCards Labels
Label(text="RC", font='bold').grid(columnspan=1, row=1, column=6)
dk_rc_var = IntVar()
dk_rc_var.set(stored_data['Daniel Keelagher']['RC'])
Label(textvariable=dk_rc_var).grid(columnspan=1, row=2, column=6)


# Buttons for other it could be something like `command=edit_bm`
Button(root, text="Edit", command=edit_dk).grid(columnspan=1, row=2, column=7)

# main loop of tkinter
root.mainloop()

# save file after closing the window
with open('settings.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(stored_data, file, indent=2)
```

This is one player, You will have to do this for each of the players in the dictionary, add all those labels in front page, all those variables, buttons, and define functions for each one of them (similarly as I have shown in this example) You will also have to match those dictionary keys (as defined in functions) (just do by example and You should be fine but I really suggest You take a look at the other answers I have given, "study them" and use those, take a look at tutorials (as someone in the comments already mentioned) or sth, because this is the worst way to do this especially because there are a lot simpler ways to do this, so here is how You CAN do it but You shouldn't because this is just objectively unnecessary)

The only thing You don't have to change is the `change` function definition and if You have questions as them.

Also I already covered saving to file in the first answer if You are interested in that.

Comment: I have noticed You applied this solution pretty well, there is a small syntax error with `\\` but otherwise seems pretty great (except for the fact that it is not the best way to do that in the first place)

Comment: in the stored data there are all the numbers but when I run my code they are all set to 0, which is fine to begin with but how do i save it once I have edited it?

Comment: @Volted edited code to include that also I forgot to set the IntVar()s to value so take a look at that too (in the code I added for every IntVar) (that was also why 0 were shown)